# Can we subsribe event listeners globally using redux to avoid passing a function as a prop from parent to multiple child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Example:

App.jsx ( Parent component )

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Pane from './tabpanel/pane';
import Registry from '../utils/registry'
import SideNavBar from './sidenav/sidenav'; 

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @class Application
     * @extends {Component}
     */
    class Application extends Component {
         constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { sidenavFunc: '',  sidenavDirFunc: ''};
            this.callbackSideNavClick = this.callbackSideNavClick.bind(this);
            this.callbackSideNavDirClick = this.callbackSideNavDirClick.bind(this);

        }

        renderContent(content, navClickFunc, navDirClickFunc) {
            return content.map((item, index) => {
                if(item.type === 'component'){
                    let componentFn = Registry[item.value];

                    return componentFn ? componentFn(index, navClickFunc, navDirClickFunc) : item.value;
                }

                if(item.type === 'link'){
                    return (<iframe className="iframe-panel" src={item.value} />);
                }

                return "";
            });
        }

        callbackSideNavClick(inputFunc, e) {       
           this.setState({
               sidenavFunc: inputFunc.bind(e)
           });
        }

        callbackSideNavDirClick(inputFunc, e) {
            this.setState({
               sidenavDirFunc: inputFunc.bind(e)
           });
        }

        render() {
            const AppConfig = this.props.config;

            const items = AppConfig.children.map((item, index) => (

                        <Pane key={index} label={item.heading}>
                            <div className="content-class">{this.renderContent(item.content, this.callbackSideNavClick, this.callbackSideNavDirClick)}</div>
                        </Pane>
                    ));

            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="left-panel">
                        <label className="panel-title" >{AppConfig.heading}</label>
                        <SearchBar />
                         <SideNavBar callbackSideNavBarOptionClick={this.state.sidenavFunc} callbackDirFileClick={this.state.sidenavDirFunc} />
                    </div>
                </div>

            );
        }
    }

    export default Application;
```

As you can see in the above code I have passed 2 functions - callbackSideNavClick() and callbackSideNavDirClick() to another component Registry.js using the code below :

```
renderContent(content, navClickFunc, navDirClickFunc) {
            return content.map((item, index) => {
                if(item.type === 'component'){
                    let componentFn = Registry[item.value];

                    return componentFn ? componentFn(index, navClickFunc, navDirClickFunc) : item.value;
                }

                if(item.type === 'link'){
                    return (<iframe className="iframe-panel" src={item.value} />);
                }

                return "";
            });
        }
```

Registry.js

```
/**
 * Add all React components to available as configuration
 * 
 * key: Put the name which will become component name in application configuration
 * value: function to returen component
 */

import React from 'react';
import FileViewerContainer from '../components/fileviewercontainer/fileviewercontainer';

const Registry = {
    FileViewerContainer: (index, navClickFunc, navDirClickFunc) =>  (<FileViewerContainer key={index} navClickFunc={navClickFunc} navDirClickFunc={navDirClickFunc} />)
};

export default Registry;
```

Like this I passed 2 functions to "FileViewerContainer" component and so on. My question is instead of passing these 2 function to multiple child as a prop, can I implement the same using any redux functionality. Probably its possible. can anyone please help me to achieve that..

Answer (score 0):

In redux, you can avoid passing functions through deep component hierarchies. You can connect any component to the redux store using `connect` function from [react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) library and get your actions/functions using *mapDispatchToProps* (2nd argument): https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

**Example from the redux docs**: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/containers/UserPage.js
See the 2nd argument of `export default connect` on the bottom. That’s where you get your actions.

Comment: can you please update my code by doing it using mapDispatchToProps as you suggested. Instead of passing to child components can you write it to app.jsx itself so that child component can access it too ?

Comment: or you can create a example with one parent and 2 child and using mapDispatchToProps how can we access that function in both the child . Please help.